# Extract character in between special character with Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Unable to extract item in between special character `=` and `&` using the following code

```
import re
tags = ["letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F"]


pat=r"^.*\='(.*)'\&.*$"
result = re.search(pat, tags [0])
```

Return `empty`.

But, I expect output as below

output

```
A B C
```

Comment: Your regexp has `'` around the capture group, but there are no quotes in the `tags` strings.

Comment: Also, you need to use a non-greedy quantifier, `.*?`

Comment: Why are you using a regexp, isn't there a library for parsing URL query strings?

Comment: You don't need to escape `=` or `&`. And your pattern will only match one of the items, not all of them, because it's anchored to the beginning and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your expected output, look for the letter after `=` sign with one or no `&` at the end:

```py
>>> re.findall('=(\w)[&]{0,1}', tags[0])
#output
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Hi @Dont, may I know the meaning of enclosed 0,1 ? Thanks

Comment: `[&]{0,1}` Means there can be either no `&` or exactly one `&`. Numbers inside`{` `}` defines the number of  cooccurrences You can take a look at [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 3):

CODE:

```
import re
tags = [
    "letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F"
    ]
pat=re.compile("(\w+)=(\w+)")
for tag in tags:
    print(pat.findall(tag))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('letter1', 'A'), ('letter2', 'B'), ('letter3', 'C')]
[('letter1', 'D'), ('letter2', 'E'), ('letter3', 'F')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually get your answer, you can just use `split`:

```
from itertools import chain
tags = ["letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F"]
tags = chain.from_iterable(item.split("&") for item in tags)
result = [item.split("=")[1] for item in tags]
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
```

Based on your pattern, you can't really get `A B C` because `C` doesn't have `=` and `&` surrounding it. This code

```
import re
from itertools import chain
tags = ["letter1=A&letter2=B&letter3=C",
    "letter1=D&letter2=E&letter3=F"]
pattern = re.compile("=(.*?)&")
result = ' '.join(chain.from_iterable([pattern.findall(item) for item in tags]))
```

gives

```
A B D E
```